# Como puedo usar las diferentes operaciones con conjuntos en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matemáticas, conjuntos

Como puedo manejar las diferentes operaciones entre conjuntos en python
Union, Intersección, Diferencia, Diferencia simétrica, Complemento, Producto cartesiano

```py
A = {1, 2, 3, 4}
B = {1, 3, 6, 7}
A ∪ B
A ∩ B
A \ B
...
...
A × B
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Por qué A y B son diccionarios?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, los operadores/métodos que puedes usar con los conjuntos los tienes en la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set. @Saelyth realmente `A` y `B` son conjuntos (`set`), los literales se declara exactamente igual que los diccionarios, solo que no se proporcionan parejas `clave: valor` `{"a":1, "b": 2, ...}` -> dict, `{1, 2, ...}` -> set

Comment: Nunca me acostaré sin aprender algo nuevo :P

Comment: @Saelyth Asi es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Crear instancias de un conjunto.

```
# Forma simple de crear un conjunto en python
x = {1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5}
print(x) # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

# Utilizando la función set(...)
x = set({1, 3, 4, 5, 1})
print(x) # {1, 3, 4, 5}

# Pasa un string a un conjunto
x = set('Hello InDeepLab')
print(x) # {'H', 'l', 'o', 'I', 'D', 'p', 'L', 'e', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'b'}

# Pasar una lista a un conjunto
x = set([1, 3, 4, 5, 1])
print(x) # {1, 3, 4, 5}

# Pasar un rango a un conjunto
x = set(range(0, 5))
print(x) # {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

*¿Que objetos son aceptados en un conjunto?*
Son aceptados solo los objetos que sean aceptados en una función  `hash(..)`

```
x = {True, 'Hello', False, 'World', 1, 4.0, 4, 0}
print(x) # {False, True, 4.0, 'Hello', 'World'}
print(hash(True) == hash(1)) # True

# En este caso las listas no son aceptadas en la función hash, por tanto no es aceptada en los conjuntos
x = {[1, 2]} # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
print(hash([1, 2])) # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Por otro lado las tuplas `tuple` si son aceptados en los conjuntos en python

```
x = {(1, 10), (2, 6)}
print(x) # {(1, 10), (2, 6)}

# como la función hash acepta las tuplas por tanto las tuplas son aceptadas en un conjunto
print(hash((1, 10))) # 3713081631925750456
```

#### ¿Como saber si un objeto esta en el conjunto?

```
# En python los conjuntos no manejan indexación
x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
print(x[0]) # TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

y por tanto para saber si un objeto esta en el conjunto se hace con el operador `in`.

```
x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
print(0 in x) # True
```

#### Operaciones entre Conjuntos

#### Union

```
# A∪B
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.union({3, 4, 5, 6}) # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} | {3, 4, 5, 6} # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

#### Intercepción

```
# A∩B
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.intersection({3, 4, 5, 6}) # {3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} & {3, 4, 5, 6} # {3, 4, 5}
```

#### Diferencia

```
# A−B
{1, 2, 3, 4}.difference({2, 3, 5}) # {1, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 4} - {2, 3, 5} # {1, 4}
```

#### Diferencia Simétrica

```
# A⊕B
{1, 2, 3, 4}.symmetric_difference({2, 3, 5}) # {1, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4} ^ {2, 3, 5} # {1, 4, 5}
```

#### Superconjunto

```
#  B⊇A 
{1, 2}.issuperset({1, 2, 3}) # False
{1, 2} >= {1, 2, 3} # False

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.issuperset({1, 2, 3}) # True
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} >= {1, 2, 3} # True
```

#### Subconjunto

```
# A⊆B
{1, 2}.issubset({1, 2, 3}) # True
{1, 2} <= {1, 2, 3} # True

{1, 5, 3, 4}.issubset({1, 2, 3}) # False
{1, 5, 3, 4} <= {1, 2, 3} # False
```

[image: Conjuntos en Python]

#### Conjuntos Disjuntos

```
# A∩B=∅
{1, 2}.isdisjoint({3, 4}) # True
{1, 2}.isdisjoint({1, 4}) # False
```

### Operaciones con elementos individuales

#### Revisar si un elemento está en un conjunto

```
2 in {1,2,3} # True
4 in {1,2,3} # False
4 not in {1,2,3} # True
```

#### Agregar elementos a un conjunto

```
s = {1,2,3}
s.add(4) # s == {1,2,3,4}
```

#### Agregar elementos a un conjunto:

```
A = {1, 2, 4}
B = {6, 4,2}
A.update(B)
print(A) # {1, 2, 4, 6}
```

#### Eliminar elementos de un conjunto:

```
# discard(...)
s = {1, 2, 3, 4}
s.discard(3) # s == {1, 2, 4}
s.discard(5) # s == {1, 2, 4}


# remove(...)
s = {1, 2, 4}
s.remove(2) # s == {1,4}
s.remove(2) # KeyError!
```

**Referencia:** [Medium - Todo lo que debes saber de conjuntos en Python — set(…) By LuisMBaezCo](https://medium.com/@LuisMBaezCo/todo-lo-que-debes-saber-de-conjuntos-en-python-set-91d9eb33c3)